# PHPStorm autocomplete twig vars

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 8.1 as IDE in a php project (laravel 4.1 project with twig on view side)

Will be great to have an autocomplete hint on vars on "twig side" like you can see here on this phpstorm plugin for symfony2:
http://symfony2-plugin.espend.de/languages/twig/index.html#phptypes

Basically in my twig view I declare the var "type" using a comment, then I would see hints on my model (farmaco):

```
   {# farmaco \Farmaco #}
   {% farmaco.  %} <-- I would see hints -->
```

Note: I'm not using Symfony, however I've the symfony plugin installed but the autocomplete doesn't work for me on twig  files for my laravel project.

Comment: Do the twig templates have a `html` or `twig` extension?

Comment: both:   `template.html.twig`,  however the problem maybe the namspace, in  L4  it's not explicit inside classes but handled by composer / autoload  classmap ..

Comment: I am running into similar issues. I am looking to see if I can get things working for a project that does not use Symfony...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `@var` annotation.
The correct form would be:

```
{# @var foo \FooService #}
{{ foo. }} <!-- press CTRL+SPACE for typehints -->
```

I got this working for a non-symfony project without issues. Be sure to check that the symfony plugin is actually enabled for the project (it isn't by default) and restart the IDE after you enable it.

Also make sure that the type-hint point to the [fully qualified class name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php).

---

As a sidenote, I have **not** (yet) gotten this to work for properties, i.e. `foo.bar.*` when the property is accessed through magic (using `__get`). For those instances the property needs to be put into a variable of its own:

```
{# @var foo \FooService #}
{{ foo.bar. }} <!-- no typehints for bar :-( -->
{% set bar = foo.bar %}
{# @var bar \BarService #}
{{ bar.  }} <!-- press CTRL+SPACE for typehints :-) -->
```

Comment: thanks, finally  var and symfony plugin make autocompletion working. 

About properties they works in my case because I use in my models generated annotations i.e.:

    @property string $permalink

they are built automagically by  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Works for Silex 2 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Works with [method references](https://github.com/klesun/deep-assoc-completion/issues/165) in _deep-assoc_ as well now, for whomever this may concern ;)